# What's the difference between "another" and "someone else"?

Tags: grammar, contemporary-english

> 1: If Henry is busy, get another person to help you.
> 2: If Henry is busy, get someone else to help you.

Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English defines *another* this way:

> not the same thing, person etc, but a different one

However, in Longman dictionary of common errors it says that when you mean a different person/thing/place, use someone else instead of another.

Comment: ANOTHER is a adjective; SOMEONE ELSE, functions as a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you get into the nitty-gritty, Different and Another can be used interchangeably, but the latter can't take a plural noun i.e, you can't say *another people*, but you can say *different people*.

Now, where does the conflict arise?

It's when their attributes such as quality, form, nature, etc come into the equation.

Another replaces someone of **similar** attributes.

Different replaces someone of **dissimilar** attributes.

For instance, let's say you're using a Reynolds pen, then if you say, 'Bring another pen.' It means that you're asking for another Reynolds pen. But if you had said, 'Bring a different pen.' It means you were asking for a pen from a different brand that's of different quality or form or nature.

So, if Henry is a plumber, then asking for another man CAN mean you're asking for another plumber.

Similarly, if you have a 1-liter bottle in your hand, and you said, "Give me another,' which means, you want another 1-liter bottle. Had you said, "Give me a different one.' Then, the shopkeeper would have given you one with a different brand, or size, or cost, etc.

Now, coming to Longman's definition: Another means not the same thing, which is right because you're talking about a different person( who can have a similar nature such as profession, etc).

Since different people/things/places have different qualities, forms, and natures, it's best to use *someone else* instead of *another*. However, when they have something similar in nature, then you can use another.